# Animated gif made in photoshop working in IE but not working in firefox

Tags: html, image, photoshop, gif

i have created a simple animated loading gif in photoshop. It works perfectly fine in Internet Explorer but not in firefox.. I have researched it so much but came up with nothing! The gif is below, and the output from photoshop is....

```html
Format: GIF
Dimensions: 300w x 300h
Size: 43.98K
Settings: Selective, 256 Colors, 100% Diffusion Dither, 42 frames, Transparency off, No Transparency Dither, Non-Interlaced, 0% Web Snap


<html>
<head>
<title>load1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (load1.jpg) -->
<img src="BrowserPreview_tmp.gif?1428467176" width="300" height="300" alt="">
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: loading.gif]

Comment: I opened your file in Photoshop then saved it as GIF using "Save for the Web" and now it works both in IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that Firefox only displays *infinitely looped* GIFs, so as a workaround, make sure it loops forever.